# React : Return a function in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a toggle component as the following.

```
export class Toggle extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            isShowBody: false
        } 
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({ isShowBody: !this.state.isShowBody })
    }

    checkbox = () => {
        return (
            <span className="switch switch-sm" >
                <label>                                    
                    <input type="checkbox" name="select" onClick={() => this.handleClick(this)}/>
                </label>
            </span>
        )
    }

    dataTest = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                Data test
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.checkbox()}
                {this.state.isShowBody && this.dataTest()}
                 
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The component, when called using `<Toggle />` in another component displays perfectly.

The problem is that I want to separate the Button and the data, so I can render `dataTest` in another component while the button is still in `Toggle.js`. How to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this Toggle.js you mean the jQuery toggle() right?

You could declare a toggle prop. So everytime you want to render either your toggleFunc or Toggle.js you just need to set true or false.

```
 render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.toggleFunc ? checkbox() : toggle()}
            {this.state.isShowBody && this.dataTest()}
             
        </div>
    );
}

<Toggle toggleFunc={true}/>
```

Comment: @AlyaKra , did my answer helped you?